# Specifying lower bound constraints also allows you to utilize members defined on the lower bound?

Tags: scala, types, type-bounds

I'm reading the book "Scala in depth", and found some points that I can't understand.

First, let's see the example about "lower bound" and "upper bound" from the book:

```
type B <: Traversable[Int]  // Upper bound definition
type B >: List[Int] // Define lower bound restriction
```

I can understand them.

But I see this sentence in page 135:

> Specifying lower bound constraints also allows you to utilize members defined on the lower bound. Upper bound constraints don’t imply what members might be on a type but are useful when combining several parameterized types.

I'm thinking is it wrong? It should be:

> Specifying **upper** bound constraints also allows you to utilize members defined on the **upper** bound. **Lower** bound constraints don’t imply what members might be on a type but are useful when combining several parameterized types.

shouldn't it?

And in my opinion,

```
class Hello[T] {
   def test1[U >: T](x: U): U = x
   def test2[U <: T](x: U): T = x   
}
```

`test1` is `lower bound` and `test2` is `upper bound`, right?

Comment: sounds right to me. upper bounds are the most commonly useful ones.

Comment: Yeah, definitely a typo in the book.